# how to add two Hexa strings in c#.net

Tags: c#

how to add two Hexa strings in C#.net

string hex1="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";

string hex2="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";

i want to get decimal value by adding these two hexa values.

Comment: I'm guessing this will get a lot of downvotes and be closed as "not a real question" unless you make substantial changes to your question..

Comment: exactly you need to specify at least where are the hex values, see this various examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: -1: It has been two hours. Edit your question, at least show examples of the strings you are trying to add. Or accept the answer given by @Eric Fortes since that seems OK based on the little information you have given so far.

Comment: I think You have to add some more BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Answer (score 3):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(hexString1, 16) + Convert.ToInt32(hexString2, 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the length of your strings (32 characters) your numbers will not fit in a `decimal` let alone `long` or `int`. A solution for this would be to use the .Net 4 `BigInteger` data type. I cannot test it here but the code would look like this

```
BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.Parse("0" + hex1, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.Parse("0" + hex2, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger result = num1 + num2;
```

If you are not on .Net 4, you will have to use a data type that can store numbers of this magnitude e.g. `double`. Since a `double` has only 8 bytes your result will loose some precision.

**EDIT**

I tested it now. Turns out you have to set a reference to System.Numerics.dll and add a `using` statement for the namespace `System.Numerics`. Also if the numbers are positive you would have to prepend the strings with a "0" to prevent them from being parsed as negative numbers.